# How to separate multiple mirrored objects?

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode, mirror, mirror-modifier

I am working on doing 2 separate models of a bionic limb (left and right) I am trying to mirror the left leg so I dont need to model both but when i apply the modifiers to the objects, it makes a single object with both the left and right combined together.

I know how to fix this with one object by separating it in edit mode but there's easily over a hundred individual objects in just one model so i wanted to see if there was any way to do this for multiple objects at one time

[image]

There's close to 150 objects so doing it the manual way in edit mode would be the last option.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the **Mirror Modifier** on all objects in question.
2. Select all objects and Duplicate all in place using <kbd>Shift+D</kbd>. Assuming all objects have their origins at the World center, else, make sure to use the **3D Cursor** as **Pivot Origin**
3. With the duplicates selected - press <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd> and then press <kbd>X</kbd> to choose the X axis as mirror axis.

This way you will get your duplicated object as mirrored copies of the originals.

***Note that the mirrored objects are Scaled by -1 on X axis, with flipped Normals so they render correctly***. If you need to apply the scale (resetting it to 1), make sure to also flip the objects Normals - Select all of them, enter **Edit Mode** and with all faces selected press <kbd>Shift+N</kbd> recalculating the face Normals to point outwards.